# Simple mulch caculator won't fire on click and no error. jQuery and straigt js

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

**I'm attempting to convert a straight javacript function to fire with jQuery .click**

I'm not getting any output errors yet it wont perform the calculation on jsfiddle.

```
var form = document.product_form_top;

function process(v) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('item_qty').value);
  value += v;
  document.getElementById('item_qty').value = value.toFixed(0);
}

    function calculate() {
      form.cubicYards.value = (form.length.value / 3) * (form.width.value / 3) * (form.depth.value / 35);

      document.getElementById('yards').innerHTML = finaloutput

      var number = parseFloat(form.item_qty.value);
      var finaloutput = number.toFixed(0);

      form.item_qty.value = form.cubicYards.value * 14.7; //calculate yards

      var number = parseFloat(form.cubicYards.value);
      var finaloutput = number.toFixed(0);

      document.getElementById('item_qty').innerHTML = finaloutput

      form.weightPounds.value = (form.length.value / 3) * (form.width.value / 3) * (form.depth.value * 21);
      form.weightPounds.value * 700;

      var number = parseFloat(form.weightPounds.value);
      var finaloutput = number.toFixed(0)

      document.getElementById('pounds').innerHTML = finaloutput
    }
```

Here's a jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/4L4St/8/

Here's a working version using onclick="calculate(); on a button to run the function. I would rather use jQuery's .click function to fire it.

http://spartonenterprises.com/store/playground-mulch

Also, I'm using toFixed(0) to remove the extra decimal points  and it appears to work when inspecting with firebug, but the visible html shows the decimals.  Strange?

Comment: You should really need spend some time on [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)ing up that code. It'll help you and everybody that wants to answer. Look what a simple change can do on readability of your code: https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/5315134. Plus proper indenting and spacing.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I will try to format it better.

Comment: Remove the line `function calculate() {` and its corresponding `}` - that function is never called; you need to put the contents of that function directly in the anonymous function that you pass to `.click()`. Then your code will run when you click the button as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/4L4St/2/ and you can start fixing the actual errors that come up in the console (like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cubicYards' of undefined`).

Comment: in your jsfiddle code you define a function in click event and then defined another function in it and you dont call it in your code, use $(document).ready(function() {}) and fix your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4L4St/5/, as an example; you have basic mistakes but with that example you can now try again.

I edit your html this way:

```
<div class="control-group clearfix">
<div class="rubber-nugget-calc">
    <label class="control-label" for="item_qty">
            <h2>Calculate Bags</h2>

    </label>
    <div class="clear"></div>Length:
    <input type="text" name="length" size="3" class="sidebarinput" />(feet) Width:
    <input type="text" name="width" size="3" class="sidebarinput" />(feet)
    <br/>Depth:
    <select class="depthselect" name="depth">
        <option value="">Please Select One</option>
        <option value="1">1 inch</option>
        <option value="2">2 inches</option>
        <option value="3">3 inches</option>
        <option value="4">4 inches</option>
        <option value="5">5 inches</option>
        <option value="6">6 inches</option>
        <option value="7">7 inches</option>
        <option value="8">8 inches</option>
        <option value="9">9 inches</option>
    </select>
    <!--Calculate Button -->
    <button class="calculate" type="button" style="float:right;" class="button">Calculate Bags Needed</button>
    <!--Results-->
    <p>You will need approximately:</p>
    <div class="calc-results">
        <div id="yards" style="display:none;">  <span> (results) </span>

        </div>  <span class="mulchspan" style="display:none;"> Total cubic yards of mulch </span>

        <input type="text" id = "cubicYards" name="cubicYards" size="2" class="sidebarresult" value="" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="pounds" style="display:none;"> <span style=""> (results) </span>

        </div>  <span class="mulchspan" style="display:none;"> Pounds of mulch (*For bulk delivery) </span>

        <input type="text" name="weightPounds" size="6" class="sidebarresult" />
    </div>
    <label class="control-label" for="item_qty">Approximate Bags Needed</label>
    <br/>
    <br/>   <small>*Note - Round up by one bag to ensure coverage / You may use the calculator or manually enter the amount.</small>

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="button-div">
            <input type="text" id="item_qty" name="item_qty" class="input-mini" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And your function like this:

```
$(".calculate").click(function () {

alert('sdfasgg');    
document.getElementById('cubicYards').value = 12;
document.getElementById('yards').style.display="";
document.getElementById('yards').innerHTML = 25;
document.getElementById('item_qty').value = 26;
document.getElementById('pounds').style.display="";    
document.getElementById('pounds').innerHTML = 27;
});
```

-------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------

This is the final fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4L4St/13/

With fixex decimals

Its doesnt calculate but now you can make all the calcs in the best way; with working code an example.

Comment: Ok, I added to nnnnnn's fiddle and here is a working edit.  http://jsfiddle.net/4L4St/9/ What am I doing wrong as far as the toFixed(0) is concerned. Does innerHTML not work with inputs?

Comment: innerHTML is for tags like div...for input you have value....i see the fiddle and looks fine...what error you have now??

Comment: I'm not getting an error necessarily, I'm wanting to remove the extra decimals within the inputs. Could I just change .innerHTML to .value?

Comment: Here's another fiddle that shows the output  http://jsfiddle.net/4L4St/14/  You can see it does remove the decimals in the html but not the inputs.

Comment: I update my answer with the corrected fiddle, please read the updated part.....saludos

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it all in....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Code here

});
```

AND

you are just defining your function....you need to call it, `calculate()`

AND

where is your form?  Your code references `product_form_top` but I don't see anything like that in your html.